# Кто переехал с adMob на Play Services - рекламма захватывает фокус

Tags: android, admob

Есть у меня ScrollView вверху или низу которого вставляется гугло-рекламма.
Всё бы хорошо, но после получения нового рекламмного объявления этот ScrollView скролит к этому сообщению.

А внутри скролла у меня, помимо всего - TextView. И Текст там не всегда короткий. И вот в середины чтения текста ррраз и оно само улетает к рекламе.

Кто-то как-то это борол?